# Creating custom route mapping for MVC .net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

i have a Post Controller that should handle routes like these:

```
mywebsite.com/post/somthing
mywebsite.com/post/post1
mywebsite.com/post/anotherpost
...
```

when i searched online for my answer i found how to register my map route like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "post",
    template: "post/{*postname}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "ReadPost" });
```

but i don't know that when i create a controller and action method for my route how to take the {*article} as an input for my method so that method know what model to return with view.

also my controller should have to handle following routes as well:

```
mywebsite.com/post/anotherpost/comments
mywebsite.com/post/anotherpost/edit
mywebsite.com/post/anotherpost/author
```

when the route ends with nothing it should be redirected to `ReadPost(string postName)`

when the route ends with comments it should be redirected to `ReadComment(string postName)`

when the route ends with edit it should be redirected to `Edit(string postName)`

and when the route ends with author it should be redirected to `ReadAuthor(string postName)`

how should i write the controller and routemapping so that proper route connect to proper action and give the method the "post name" as input?

Comment: You wrote, "...how to take the {*article} as an input..." What is `article`?

Comment: is {antherpost} in your question is the string postName?

Comment: @ShaunLuttin sorry, that was a typo i fixed it

Comment: @Liran yep, it's a string name.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mixed the route a bit, you should not name your controller like the HTTP verb its going to use, its the other way around, you should use 
http://www.domain.com/article and create actions in your controller to match the
HTTP verbs like so (im using web api cause i had a project opened already):

```
public class ArticleController : ApiController
{
    // GET: api/Default
    public IEnumerable<string> Get()
    {
        return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
    }

    // GET: api/Default/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        return "value";
    }

    // POST: api/Default
    public void Post([FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // PUT: api/Default/5
    public void Put(int id, [FromBody]string value)
    {
    }

    // DELETE: api/Default/5
    public void Delete(int id)
    {
    }
}
```

and then you can use routes in apiconfig.cs

like this:

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

here are some [REST best practice](http://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api) hope this will help.

EDIT:

just to clarify i dont like what i done here and to my opinion its all kinds
of wrong but to help you get started here is the controller code:

```
public class PostController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult ReadPost(string postName)
    {
        return View("~/views/home/Index.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult Comments(string postName)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your application description page.";

        return View("~/views/home/Index.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult Edit(string postName)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View("~/views/home/Index.cshtml");
    }

    public ActionResult Author(string postName)
    {
        ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

        return View("~/views/home/Index.cshtml");
    }

}
```

and here is route file :

```
public class RouteConfig
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        //routes.MapRoute(
        //    name: "Default",
        //    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        //    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        //);




        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "postOnlyParam",
           url: "post/{postName}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "ReadPost", postName = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );

        routes.MapRoute(
          name: "post",
          url: "post/{action}/{postName}",
          defaults: new { controller = "Post", action = "ReadPost", postName = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );


    }
}
```

i have tested it and does what you want if i understand your question.

Comment: not the answer i was looking for. the code segment you are referring to was coppiend from this [link](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/routing.html) which is i slightly modified to point out the fact about how i am planning on modifying my code and mentioned that the code mapping i putted there would only work to answer the first part of my question not the second part, i fixed the article name issue anyway. the controller and mapping method you putted does the same job as the default mapping in MVC core. which i don't need here

Comment: @soorena12 check the answer now please.